# NHibernate doesn't save one property only

Tags: c#, sql, .net, nhibernate

I'm trying to update a single column in the table. No UPDATE issued whatsoever (checked using SQL Profiler). No errors.

- Class mapping has `dynamic-update="true"`.
- No versioning enabled on the class.
- Flush mode Commit.
- Property mapped without any insert/update modifiers (`<property name="Deleted" />`).
- Property is auto-implemented (`public virtual bool Deleted { get;set;}`).
- NH 3.3.0, .NET 4, x64.

  ```
  using (var transaction = this._session.BeginTransaction())
  {
      try
      {
          var order = this.session.Load<Order>(id);
          order.Deleted = true;
          this._session.Update(order);
          transaction.Commit();
      }
      catch (Exception)
      {
          transaction.Rollback();
          throw;
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: If you break on the transaction commit line, is _session.IsDirty() true? Is Deleted an auto-property or does it have a backing field? And you don't need to call Update on the session but I doubt that's the issue

Comment: Are you using versioning as well?

Comment: We can't guess what's inside `Repository.Load`. Please replace that line with `var order = _session.Get<Order>(id)`. With that, `_session.Update` should not be needed. You don't have to manually rollback the transaction either.

Comment: @DiegoMijelshon my bad, see updated question. The problem with Get is that it performs a query to get the entity; I'm trying to make it so that a single UPDATE is issued for a single column and no SELECTs.

Comment: The fact that you are using two different `session`s (`session` and `_session`) is probably the root of the problem here.

Comment: @KT nope that's just a typo when I pasted the code here. The accepted answer is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the comments, what you are trying to do is create a proxy without getting the current state from the DB (using `session.Load`), then issue a dynamic update.

This will not work. NHibernate does not record individual changes to properties; instead, it:

- Compares the current state of tracked entities against a snapshot of the property values that were retrieved from the database.
- Based on that, determines which entities are dirty (i.e. have changes)
- It generates the SQL update statement. If using `dynamic-update`, it will only contain the modified properties.

If you use `session.Load`, as soon as you access the `Deleted` property, NH will load the record from the database. Whether you use `session.Load` or `session.Get`, `session.Update` on an already tracked entity is a no-op.

Alternatively, if you already have the state for all the order properties, you can update without loading:

```
var order = GetTheOrderFromMemory();
order.Deleted = true;
session.Update(order);
transaction.Commit();
```

This will **not** respect `dynamic-update`, as NH doesn't have a snapshot to compare with...

...which is why HQL is the only way to do a one-shot update of an individual property.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does seem to be the case. I'm going to stick with Load and Update (which for some reason started working by getting and updating - which it didn't do before). Thanks for the help.

Comment: Good to hear. But as said above, `Update` is not needed if you are already `Load`ing.